# Atlassian Stash Git clone error fatal: unable to access 'http://admin@localhost:7990/scm/gmpp/gmpp.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, http-status-code-403, bitbucket-server

Following this link: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Getting+started+with+Git+and+Stash

I just installed Atlassian Stash, created a new project and repository, but immediately got this error, any idea how to fix this?

```
git clone http://admin@localhost:7990/scm/gmpp/gmpp.git
Cloning into 'gmpp'... fatal: unable to access 'http://admin@localhost:7990/scm/gmpp/gmpp.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: Stash developer here, if you get stuck try raising a support ticket so we can ask for your logs.

https://support.atlassian.com/

Comment: I raise the question here but nobody replies. Let me try support. https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/282781/stash-git-clone-returns-the-requested-url-returned-error-403

Comment: I tried support site, but never received the "Verify your email address".

Answer (score 1):

Change to https works.

However, I got a new error in this command:  git push origin master
The application has failed to start because libcurl-4.dll was not found